# Sony Xperia U not working after failed update

Tags: updates, sony-xperia-u

I've been having problems for some time with my phone connecting to my pc/charger which Sony advised me to correct with the latest update.

However, when I tried the update failed twice and now my phone just shows an error screen with an exclamation mark and phone.

Can't do anything with it at all.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can I ask if you had unlocked the bootloader?

Comment: Please elaborate more on this? What screenshots? What happened exactly? Did you use Sony PC Companion suite?

Answer (score 1):

As it is a software issue, and you have not used a custom ROM, the best thing to do would be to send it to the Sony repair centre.